# Wait and retry shell script till powershell script prints specific message

Tags: powershell, shell, azure-cli

This may seem like a trivial question so please bear with me. I am very new to this.

I have a shell script (`.sh file`) that reads some config from a json file and runs a powershell script. This PowerShell script installs some predefined software on an Azure VM (using the Azure CLI).
After which it prints "deployment done". If the deployment fails for any reason, it prints "deployment failed". It also restarts the VM a few times during this process, so it prints other debug messages like "rebooting", "rebooted successfully", etc.

**My question is, how do I make the shell script wait till I am able to read the message "deployment done"**. If I see a "deployment failed" message, I need to retry running the script 3 times (this can be achieved by a loop I guess) before aborting the process.

Pseudo code for the shell script

```
vm_name=`abc`
echo ">> installing software on $vm_name"

az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript \
-g $rg_name --name $resource_grp \
--scripts script.ps1 \
--parameters "name=$software_name" \
             "ipAddress=$ip_add" \
```

Pseudo code for script.ps1

```
Write-Host ">> installing software"

// try to install
$installResult = Start-process -filepath "// file to software" -Wait -Passthru

if($installResult.ExitCode -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "<< Rebooting to complete the installation"
} 
elseif($exitResult.ExitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Host "<< deployment failed"
}

Restart-Computer -Force
Write-Host "<< Rebooting"
Write-Host "<< deployment done"
```

Comment: Just a comment for the .ps1 script. I’d change the ending too. 
``write-host “Rebooting” ; Restart-Computer -wait -for powershell -Force ; Write-Host “Deployment Done”``

Comment: I should’ve mentioned it only works of being run remotely(PSRemoting) but it would restart the remote computer and then wait for powershell to be reachable again before continuing

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the comment before refreshing the page. Here is the reference for anyone looking [Example 6: Restart a remote computer and wait for PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-7.2#example-6-restart-a-remote-computer-and-wait-for-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

To add to my comment, I don’t know anything about shell scripts but an answer for using PowerShell remoting, you can rewrite your PowerShell script it as such,

```
$failedcounter = 0

Do{ 
Write-Output “Installing Software”

$Install = invoke-command $VM -ScriptBlock {Start-Process <install.exe> -Wait -PassThru }

If($install.exitcode -eq 0){
    Write-Output “Rebooting”
    Restart-Computer $VM -wait -for powershell -Force
    Write-output “Deployment Done”

}Else{
    Write-output “Deployment Failed, retrying” 

$failedcounter++

}

}until(($install.exitcode -eq 0) -or ($failedcounter -eq 3))
```